# How to run PHP code from fopen/file_get_contents?

Tags: php, mysqli, fopen

I am making a mail application that I am using to send out invoices, I have an HTML email invoice template.

```
    <?php
include 'dbconfig.php';

$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {


$to = "name@example.com";
$subject = "Invoice Test " . date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
$invoice = fopen("invoice.html", "r") or die("Unable to open invoice template file");
$message = fread($invoice, filesize("invoice.html"));

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: billing@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'BCC: billing@example.com' . "\r\n";


mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

echo $message;
fclose ($invoice);


}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

This code works perfectly, however I want to run PHP code in the template file, such as `<? echo $row[id]; ?>` to fill in the blanks of the template  with data from the MySQL call. How can I do this? fopen doesn't run PHP code. Kinda like `require_once` but where I can use it in this application.

If this can't be done, I will just resort to including index-template.php in the main document and then formatting that secondary document at `$message = ' <html code> ';` - it just makes updating the template more difficult.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use some kind of templating language, like Twig or Smarty?

Comment: The "template" I am using is just HTML, I want to put some PHP in there. I would prefer to just do it like this.

Comment: What about you just replace the values? So don't use variables but placeholders

Comment: I don't understand @Lithilion

Comment: Use placeholders like ____NAME____ in the template, so you can str_replace() them when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that with what you have now, would be to use output buffering to capture the output and then include the file instead of reading it:

```
// start output buffering
ob_start();

// include your file, which parses the php in it
include 'invoice.html';

// close the output buffer and get its contents
$message = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this solution? I would prefer to use a templating language myself, but this is what the OP wants and it works.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I didn't down vote it though.

Comment: @Tony How is it not working? It should as far as I can see.

Comment: sorry, it is technically working in that it runs the PHP but it is not connecting to the MySQL Database and working in conjunction with the other code. <? echo $row['id']; ?> is not returning anything.

Comment: @Tony That is strange as the variable scope is inherited. Are you sure short tags are enabled or are you doing any other operations in the template file that might affect your variable?

Comment: @Tony That is really weird. Is it just the `$row` variable, can you access for example `$to` or `$subject`? All your variables should be available so perhaps the template is doing something with them.

Comment: Nope, can't access any variable ($to or $subject) any advice?

Comment: @Tony I am afraid not, I cannot reproduce this at all; I have just included a html file with php in a php script, used output buffering like in my answer and it works without any problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182147/discussion-between-tony-and-jeroen).

Comment: I sent you a chat, I sent you code, it doesn't pass variables it seems...

Comment: The variable needs to be above includes. That will make it work.

Comment: @Tony Obviously, otherwise it will be undefined. But in your code you set the message in the loop so the variable is already defined there. You should add the modified code to your question as I am not sure anymore of what you are doing exactly.

Comment: What you have above will not work, switch the order put include under $message.

Comment: @Tony No, you need to make sure `$row` is defined before the include and message will be the output of your template file with the variables parsed.